# Get Mobile number programmatically : android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating an app with phone otp verification ...
how i can get the current phone number from android device ?

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+mPhoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            return;
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
```

i tried this but it returns an empty string...
can you suggest any other methods to get phone number from device...
if the phone is dual sim .. how i can get both the numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the permission to manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: @commonman are you able to view the number in the settings? Settings > About > Phone Identity

Comment: no...phone number status is unknown in the settings

Comment: Have you tried subscription manager? List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptions SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext()).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList() Loop through this and log the .getNumber(). This might work with Android 5.1+

Comment: it returns null